# How to check if a number ends with 1 or 11?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to differentiate if a number ends either with 1 or 11, if i use `modulo 10` the remained for 201 and 211 would still be 1 , but I want them to print different results, also for all the other numbers ending like this. For my programms input I am using `x = ARGV[0].to_i` maybe that can help

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre].

Comment: You could check `modulo 100`. Or, you could use `String#end_with?` (or a regex, or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
211.to_s.end_with?('11')
#=> true
211.to_s.end_with?('1')
#=> true

213.to_s.end_with?('11')
#=> false
```

Or use `ARGV[0]` directly which returns a string already: `ARGV[0].end_with?('11')`

Answer (score 0):

> if i use modulo 10 the remained for 201 and 211 would still be 1

That's because `num % 10` returns just the very last digit. To get the last 2 digits, you have to use `num % 100`:

```
12345 % 10     #=> 5
12345 % 100    #=> 45
12345 % 1000   #=> 345
12345 % 10000  #=> 2345
```

To check whether an integer ends with `11` or `1` you could use:

```
if num % 100 == 11
  # num ends with 11
elsif num % 10 == 1
  # num ends with 1
end
```

There's also [`Integer#digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) which returns the digits as an array, starting with the right-most digit:

```
12345.digits   #=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

So checking that array's first and second element is another option:

```
if num.digits[0] == 1
  if num.digits[1] == 1
    # num ends with 11
  else
    # num ends with 1
  end
end
```